# Show that the equivalence classes of $\sim$ are left cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations

Let $H \leq G$ and define a relation on $G$ by $x \sim y$ if $y^{-1}x \in H$.  Show that $\sim$ is an
equivalence relation on $G$ and then show that the equivalence classes of $\sim$ are left cosets of $H$ in $G$.

I was given the following question as an assignment and I have proved that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $G$, that was not difficult.  The second part of the question asks us to show that the equivalence classes of $~$ are left cosets of $H$ in $G$.  I know that a  left coset is $gH = \{gh : h \in H\}$ what must I show prove that the equivalence classes of $\sim$ are left cosets?

I think the boils down to more of a question about proving equivalence classes more than anything.  So my real question is how do you prove or show equivalence classes of a relation? I think if I was clear on that the question will be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your job, if you choose to accept it, is to take any two elements $x,y \in G$ and to prove that $x \sim y$ if and only if there exists $g \in G$ such that $x \in gH$ and $y \in gH$.

Comment: And also unique! $g$ with the equivalance relation,that means if we have a $g$ and an $f$ then we should have that $g^{-1}f\in H$.